# Compute Tangent vector over 2D Points

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have computed the **contours** of an object in an image. Now I have a **2D array**, each of element representing **X & Y** coordinates of a contour point.

---

Now, I want to compute a **tangent vector** over each point and **angle** between them (contour point and tangent vector).

---

My points are ordered. i.e. p[i+1,] is next to p[i,] and my path is closed. i.e. p[0] is next to p[N-1] (If I consider N points. The image of contour points is attached below.

I have done a lot of search but never find any clue. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are your points ordered?  i.e. is `p[i,]` "next to" `p[i+1,]`  And is your path closed? i.e. is `p[0]` next to p[N-1]` (if you have N points)?

Comment: Sorry @bogovicj for late reply. yes my points are ordered and it is a closed path.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial way is :

`Tangent[i] = Normalize(Contour[i+1] - Contour[i-1])`

You would simply need to take care of boundary conditions if any!

Comment: Thanks @Narra. But I think we compute gradient using this method.

Comment: When using the contour points directly this gives tangent(approx) direction.